# Can I hide questions based on tag name(s) from my feed?

Tags: support, filtering, ignored-tags, rss, front-page

TL;DR; Question is deprecated.

The default SO algorithm, made finding the right questions to answer very difficult as questions were all over the place, different tags, many topics.

The question was how to curate the SO feed to our personal tastes and interests, with filters like "minimum reputation of the user who asks"... or "tags that are not of my interest at all"... so that we can weed out topics were not expert in, or we have no interest in.

SO made improvement to heuristics, and it also provides now two useful tag based filtering mechanisms:

- Whitelist tags.
- Ignored tags.

Therefore, question is deprecated.

Comment: So, all low rep users can't ask a decent question?

Comment: Did you investigate if filters work for you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63888/filter-stack-exchange-homepage

Comment: I never said that, don't put words on someone else's mouth. I would just like to have the chance to filter out questions based on filters.

Comment: @rene That link leads to a dead end.

Comment: @Adrian, you could put `[jquery]` in your ignored tags list.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar How about this: http://stackexchange.com/filters

Comment: @rene thanks for the hint. That is a white-list style of filtering but I'll use it anyways. I was asking for a black-list filter. Any fast growing feed that gets out of control needs one.

Comment: You can ignore the tag, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do

Comment: @Stijn you saved my life! U should post it as an answer... And please forgive my ignorance on the matter.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar If I post that as an answer, it is automatically converted to a comment for being trivial. I don't know at this point how to handle duplicates that are on MSE.

Comment: I recommend that the question body (not the question title) be edited a bit to be slightly less hostile. Perhaps we could have something like this:      Suppose that I was looking at questions tagged with `jQuery`. How do I filter them more?

I have a lot of difficulty finding questions which I want to answer.   

It might be best if the main feed had filters such as:   
* "minimum reputation of the user who asked the question"      
* "exclude tags I am not knowledgeable about". 

Are those features to filter the feed out there?
How do I personalize my view of the main SO page?

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon thanks for pointing that out. I made the changes...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you hover over a tag name, a pop-up appears with a star in the top left corner. Click twice on the star so that it becomes a red cross (the star cycles through three states: [normal, favorite, ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)). This marks the tag as ignored. When a tag is ignored, you won't see any question with this tag in your feed, on the main page or on `/questions` pages.

In addition, the home page of Stack Overflow learns from your habits and has heuristics to show questions that are more likely to interest you. See [the blog post announcing this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [my user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4211/automatically-hide-ignored-questions) to hide questions you're not interested in.  It won't fill up the front page, but it makes it easier to see the questions you are more interested in.