# Excluding a tag

Tags: support, tags

I am regularly answering questions about the Python programming language. However many of the questions are in fact not about Python itself, but about a very popular webserver called Django. How can I exclude those questions from the ones I get to see, so exclude the [django] tag?

Comment: Yes, you can ignore them, see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251962/can-i-hide-questions-based-on-tag-names-from-my-feed).

Comment: Django is not a web server (though it does contain one for testing purposes). It [could be described as a web framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29).