# Subscribe to questions with [tag] and not [another tag]

Tags: support, tags, ignored-tags, subscriptions

I subscribed to [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) by email, but got a lot of questions about [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular), because almost every question about [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) has [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript). So, I'm forced to scroll over dozens of not interesting questions while searching for ones that I can answer.

I marked [agnular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agnular) as ignored as described [there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251962/can-i-hide-questions-based-on-tag-names-from-my-feed). But I still receiving email with angular-questions. I have tried to subscrite to [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) alone, and to `Favourite tags` - no difference.

How should I setup email notifications to receive [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) questions, but not [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) ones?